# Why is this mod_rewrite RewriteRule directive not working in the .htaccess file?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mac-osx-server, php5

I've got a site that was hosted on a linux el cheapo hosting service that I'm migrating to my Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard Server server running Apache 2.2.8 & PHP 5.2.5 w/rewrite_module enabled and `AllowOverride All`, but I'm running into an issue with the following lines in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^view/([^/\.]+)/?$ /view.php?item=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^order/([^/\.]+)/?$ /order.php?item=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

As you can see, I've commented out the `RewriteRule` directives for `/view/` and `/order/`, so I'm only dealing with `/category/`. When I attempt to load `http://domain.tld/category/2/` it runs `category.php` (I've added debug code to confirm), but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` comes through as `/category/2/` and `$_GET['category']` comes through as empty.

I'm usually fine with troubleshooting .htaccess files and mod_rewrite directives, but this one's got me stumped for some reason.

**Update**: I followed [Josh's suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/77347/why-is-this-modrewrite-rewriterule-directive-not-working-in-the-htaccess-file/77362#77362) and here's the what's dumped to `mod_rewrite.log` when I try to access `http://domain.tld/category/2/`:

```
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /category/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/category/13'
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (1) pass through /category/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6aa98/subreq] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] add path info postfix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6aa98/subreq] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php/13 -> category.php/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6aa98/subreq] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] applying pattern '^category/([^/\.]+)/?$' to uri 'category.php/13'
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6aa98/subreq] (1) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] pass through /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] add path info postfix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php -> /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php/13 -> category.php/13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] applying pattern '^category/([^/\.]+)/?$' to uri 'category.php/13'
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b5ea98/initial] (1) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] pass through /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/category.php
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/13'
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (1) pass through /13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] strip per-dir prefix: /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/13 -> 13
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (3) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] applying pattern '^category/([^/\.]+)/?$' to uri '13'
65.19.81.253 - - [22/Oct/2009:17:31:53 --0400] [domain.tld/sid#100aae0b0][rid#100b6ea98/subreq] (1) [perdir /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/] pass through /Library/WebServer/Documents/tld.domain.www/13
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add this to your .htaccess file

```
Options -MultiViews
```

i've had the same problem for hours

i don't know why, but it's turned on by default on OSX

it produces your error because when you try loading *category/* it finds the *category.php* and redirects everything after the slash to that file

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to httpd.conf? If so please add to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/mod_rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

And post what that log says when you load `/category/2`. Remove this after you get the information you need from it -- it's very wasteful of server resources.

EDIT:

Thanks for the log. Something is rewriting the URL to: `/category.php/13`. Any other RewriteRules? Are you using FastCGI? What if you rename `category.php` to something else, like `Category.php` or `display_category.php`?

EDIT2:

Since something seems to be rewriting `/category/(.*)` to `/category/$1`, and we don't know what it is, why don't you change:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^category.php/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Done. See updated question.

Comment: No other rules. In fact, I fully deleted all but `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]` from the `.htaccess` file. Renaming `category.php` to `display_category.php` and changing the substitution to `/display_category.php?category=$1` worked, but I'd really like it to work with the file still named `category.php`.

Comment: Something is rewriting requests for `/category/(.*)` to `/category.php/$1`... Do you use FastCGI PHP?

Comment: Changing the RewriteRule to match against category.php also worked. Interestingly, `^view/` and `^order/` have the same issue... I'm not using FastCGI PHP, AFAIK, it's all a base install of Leopard Server. The only other mod_rewrite rules I know are applied are `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE` and then `RewriteRule .* - [F]` and that's true for all sites. Maybe one of the other Apache modules (or the PHP5 module) is doing this for convenience?

Comment: Also, there is are no `category` or `view` directories to be causing conflicts.

Comment: Hm. Well without seeing all of httpd.conf I'm not sure what's rewriting the requests to `/category.php/$1` but I'm glad it's working now! I suspect that something sees a PHP script with that basename and rewrites. (That's why I suspected FastCGI PHP). Do the same rewrite change for `/view` and `/order` and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably being an idiot here, but isn't that the expected behavior?  Mod_rewrite changes the URL inline for finding the file, the environment variables seen by PHP don't normally change.

I think you have to parse the REQUEST_URI string to pull out the category variable.

Mark

Comment: $_GET isn't an environment variable -- it's a superglobal containing the result of query strings. What he's trying to do should work.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that because `RewriteRule ^category/([^/\.]+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]` included the substitution string `/category.php?category=$1` that it would outright replace the URI, even for internal redirects. [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule] notes that "The URL is completely replaced by the Substitution and the rewriting process continues until all rules have been applied, or it is explicitly terminated by a L flag."

Also, if I change the flag to `[R,L]` it exhibits the same behavior and doesn't redirect.

Comment: It should be working as you originally expected, although the [R] flag not taking effect is unusual. Can you enable the rewrite debug log?

Comment: **@mfarver** You are correct that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` comes through as `/category/2/` even after it's fixed, but the question was really about the rewrite not working and so `$_GET['category']` coming through blank.